# Session lost occasionally after successful login

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, session

I am having a strange issue with my login web page, where user's login session gets lost **occasionally** after successful login.

When the user accesses the next page after login, it would be redirected back to the login page because the login session doesn't exist.

It happens about 10% of the time randomly (seems so) among many users, and usually the same user who experienced this would get in after the second try. It doesn't seem to me that the system was busy when this happens.

Here's the login process:

1. User enters the username and password on the login page (login.asp),
   then the login credentials are sent from the login page (login.asp)
   to a Asp.Net login handler (LoginHandler.ashx) via an javascript
   Ajax call.
2. The Login Handler then validates the credential and set a login
   session (`Session["CC_VendorInfo"]`) which includes user's information.
3. Then the Login Handler sends back an OK response to the Ajax call.
   Upon receipt of the OK response, the javascript on Login.asp would
   send the user to the next page.
4. When user requests the next page, the server tries to retrieve info
   from the Login session (`Session["CC_VendorInfo"]`). If the session is null then it would
   redirect the user back to the login page.

I have some debug log on the server to print out the login session contents which proves that the session is successfully set in Step 2. And I also have log showing that in Step 4, the login session sometimes is NULL.

**More Notes**: 
The application is deployed on a standard Windows virtual machine in Azure, so the session management limitations caused by load balancing don't seem to apply to this problem.

What would be the possible cause of this issue? Any answer is much appreciated!

Part of the code in **Login.asp**:

```
function Login() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Home/LoginHandler.ashx",
        data: {
            user: $("#UserName").val(),
            pswd: $("#PassWord").val()
        },
        success: function (response) {
            ProcessLogin(response);
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert("Failed to login.");
        }
    })
    return false;
}
function ProcessLogin(response) {
    // ... ...
    if (response == 'OK') {
        window.location.href = strNextUrl;
    } else {
        alert("Failed to login.");
    }
}
```

Part of the code in **LoginHandler.ashx**:

```
    if (CheckCredential(context, sUserName, sPassword))
    {
        ClsVendorInfo oVendorInfo = new ClsVendorInfo();
        oVendorInfo.iVendorID = iVendorID;
        oVendorInfo.sUserName = sUserName;

        // set the login session here
        ClsCommonUI.SetVendorInfoSession(oVendorInfo);

        sResp = "0|OK";
    }
```

A function in an **utility** class to set the login session:

```
    static class ClsCommonUI
    {
        // ... ...

        public static bool SetVendorInfoSession(ClsVendorInfo oVendorInfo)
        {
            ClsVendorInfo oSessVendorInfo = HttpContext.Current.Session["CC_VendorInfo"] as ClsVendorInfo;
            if (oSessVendorInfo != null && 
                (oSessVendorInfo.iVendorID != oVendorInfo.iVendorID || 
                 oSessVendorInfo.iUserID != oVendorInfo.iUserID))
            {
                DebugLog(oSessVendorInfo,
                    string.Format("Login Session Changed [{0}] (before): {1}",
                        HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID,
                        oSessVendorInfo.Print()));
            }
            // update session
            HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove("CC_VendorInfo"); 
            HttpContext.Current.Session["CC_VendorInfo"] = oVendorInfo.Clone();

            oSessVendorInfo = HttpContext.Current.Session["CC_VendorInfo"] as ClsVendorInfo;

            // I can see the session content being print out in the debug log
            DebugLog(oSessVendorInfo,
                string.Format("SetVendorInfoSession [{0}]: {1}",
                    HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID,
                    oSessVendorInfo.Print()));

            // ... ...

            return true;
        }

        // ... ...
    }
```

When the user requests the **next page**, here's the code to **check the Login session**:

```
    public static int GetVendorInfo(HttpRequest oReq,
                                    ClsDBAccess oDBAccess,
                                    out ClsVendorInfo oVendorInfo,
                                    [CallerFilePath] string sCallerFileName = "")
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

        ClsVendorInfo oSessionVendorInfo = context.Session["CC_VendorInfo"] as ClsVendorInfo;

        if (oSessionVendorInfo != null &&
            oSessionVendorInfo.iVendorID != 0)
        {
            // continue processing
            //... ...
        }
        else
        {
            // No Session - go back to login
            RedirectToLogin(HttpContext.Current);
        }
    }
```

Comment: (1) Check your browser traffic (e.g. with Chrome F12 tools) and see if your session ID is changing, which could happen if there is a concurrency problem with your requests. (2) Is your solution load balanced? Maybe you are hopping between nodes (3) Check event logs for app pool recycle; that would effectively reset all sesssions

Comment: @John Thanks for the comments. 1) I can't recreate the problem myself so I am not sure if the session ID has changed on the user's browser, but can you elaborate about what concurrency problem it might be? In my login.asp code, it requests the next page after receiving the response from the server, which means the session should have been successfully created? 2) I am not sure about the load balance. The page is hosted on the Azure server.. 3) if app pool recycles, all session will be gone, which is not what I've seen...

Comment: A race condition could occur, for example, if there are multiple AJAX requests in flight and they return different session cookies. All cookies other than the last one to finish would be lost, along with their variables. BTW are you using In-Proc session? See [this article](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/cloud/platform-as-a-service/managing-session-state-in-windows-azure-what-are-the-options/) on why that may not work so well in Azure.

Comment: @John Thanks again for your comments. 1) I have a mechanism to prevent user from double clicking the Login button, so I am not sure how likely multiple AJAX calls can be made.. 2) My application is deployed on a standard Windows virtual machine in Azure, hence the problem caused by the load balancer doesn't seem to apply. Are there any other possibilities?

Comment: User has multiple tabs open? Your business logic is tripping over a session fixation mitigation? Multimedia content being returned too slowly and shows up with the old session cookie when it arrives? Hard to guess when I know so little about your site. I would consider adding more logging statements to output IP address, session ID, user name, etc. in all logic branches, so you can see if there is any pattern or something you're not thinking of.

Comment: Speaking of session fixation, you might have a [vulnerability](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Session_fixation). If the session info doesn't match the login credentials you should probably do a full reset (i.e. drop the session entirely) and start over. A malicious user may be able to put his own session cookie on a legitimate user's browser, which would grant them a certain level of unauthorized access.

Answer (score 0):

If this isn't your issue, I can delete this answer.

Chrome's new SameSite change for cookies is about to drop or already did.  If you don't have SameSite attribute on a cookie, chrome will just drop the cookie outright.  If it is set to Lax, then all cross-domain iframes will drop the cookie.  If this works fine in IE, then this is probably your issue.  If you use SameSite=None, cross domain iframe works, but older browsers may stop working, too...

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I am not sure if it always works on IE or not (I can't recreate the issue myself). My users are mostly using FF, Chrome, and Safari. The Login page and the LoginHandler page are on the same domain but different application pool. Not sure if this is bound to the SameSite rule..?